# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Container must be non-null

Tags: java, eclipse, grouplayout

The error below appeared out of nowhere. I tried to check for the null value but could not find it. All variables are set as global private variables. Would anyone know what is the error?

```
 GroupLayout gl_pnlIntroToQuiz = new GroupLayout(pnlIntroToQuiz);
    gl_pnlIntroToQuiz.setHorizontalGroup(
        gl_pnlIntroToQuiz.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_pnlIntroToQuiz.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(171)
                .addComponent(txtAreaIntro, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(192, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, gl_pnlIntroToQuiz.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(602, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnBeginQuiz)
                .addContainerGap())
    );
    gl_pnlIntroToQuiz.setVerticalGroup(
        gl_pnlIntroToQuiz.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_pnlIntroToQuiz.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(93)
                .addComponent(txtAreaIntro, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 121, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnBeginQuiz)
                .addContainerGap())
    );
    pnlIntroToQuiz.setLayout(gl_pnlIntroToQuiz);
```

The error given is below

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Container must be non-null
at javax.swing.GroupLayout.<init>(Unknown Source)
at IT_IA_Quiz.views.quizPsychology2.<init>(quizPsychology2.java:282)
at IT_IA_Quiz.views.quizPsychology2$1.run(quizPsychology2.java:59)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `pnlIntroToQuiz` is clearly null. You have to initialize it before creating a `GroupLayout` that references it.

Comment: @Mureinik I did, I set the pnlIntroToQuiz as a global variable 
private JPanel pnlIntroToQuiz;

Comment: Then please share that code - your mistakes is probably somewhere there.

Comment: @Mureinik ok, I'll try. It seems even though I have the 4 spaces, the code does not register it so I can't add it. do you have any tips please? Thanks

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add it. Code doesn't format in the comments.

Comment: @Mureinik, I know. I edit it in the question. The 4 spaces somehow applies only to the first line, it forces me to hard code line by line.

Comment: Edit it in and ping me in the comment, I'll take a look and help format it for you

Comment: @Mureinik the link to the code is here. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhH5KJoRYPgyzW9_3HDA6hu_uzaj

Comment: @Mureinik were you able to open the link with the code?

Comment: @Mureinik it's ok, I solved my error. Thanks for the help!